# android activity not found urlconnection

Tags: android

I am trying to access a web page using android urlconnection and I have succeeded even in parsing it using jsoup. However when I click the listview row,The link does not open on browser.this is my code and .xml. Please help me.

```
logcat

06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=Full story: Daily Mail  }
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at com.omeja.bbcsport.BBCActivity.onListItemClick(BBCActivity.java:234)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-21 14:40:07.428: E/AndroidRuntime(10510):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //
            //
            Document doc;
            try {
                // doc = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();
                // String title = doc.title();
                // Elements links = doc.getElementsByClass("external-link");
                doc = Jsoup.parse(result, url1);
                Elements links  = doc.select("h2 ~ p");
                // Elements links = doc.select("h2.cross-head");
                // Elements links = doc.select("a.external-link");
                // Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
                // Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");
                //
                //
                for (Element link : links) {

                    Elements tableDatas = link.getElementsByTag("p");
                    //Elements tableDatas2 = link.getElementsByTag("a");
                    if (tableDatas.hasText()) {
                        String rowData = tableDatas.text();
                        // rowData2 = tableDatas2.text();
                        //if (!tableRowStrings.contains(rowData)) {
                            tableRowStrings.add(rowData);

                        //}

                    }
                    //

                }
                //
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        BBCActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        tableRowStrings);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                //

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        //

    }

    //
    @Override 
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something when a list item is clicked

        //  String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
          Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) tableRowStrings.get(position));
          //  Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

manifest

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.omeja.bbcsport.BBCActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call you intent as it follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(uri); // If you have the url, i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Let me know about your progress.

Answer (score 0):

call the activity like that and The URL must always start with `"http://`" or `"https://"` so I use this snipped of code.In some cases URL may start with `"www".` In this case you will get an exception:

```
    String url = "http://www.example.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

You can see the documentation of [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)

Comment: Thanks  figured it out after looking at your code. The challenge was that what i am displaying to the user is not the actual url but its text.so I had to find away using arraylist to store the link separately and activate it on click. my second challenge now is to activate clicking only when the listview row is a link and not to allow all rows to be clickable. any ideas????part1 was solved

Comment: i used 2 arraylists as below   for (Element link : links) {

     Elements tableDatas = link.getElementsByTag("p");
     Elements tableDatas2 = link.getElementsByTag("a");
     if (tableDatas.hasText()) {
      String rowData = tableDatas.text();
      String lnk = tableDatas2.attr("href");
    //  String tot = rowData+"\n"+lnk;
      // rowData2 = tableDatas2.text();
      //if (!tableRowStrings.contains(rowData)) {
       tableRowStrings.add(rowData);
       tableRowStrings2.add(lnk);
      //}

     }

Comment: guys sorry about the code.how do i paste code in comments here?